# Is it performant to put all Log tables into a different database catalog in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

Supposing we have a web application, which uses a **SQL Server 2005** server database, would it be better for **performance** to move all our custom **Log** tables to a specific catalog?

### Scenario

Our web application today uses different catalogs from SQL Server. Each catalog have tables related to a problem (domain/subject): `db_financial`, `db_corporative`, etc.

These catalogs already have many different **log tables**, to register a history of changes made by users during application usage: `tb_log_product`, `tb_log_customer`, `tb_log_provider_prices`, etc.

### The goal

The goal is to know if there is any advantage on moving log tables to a specific catalog.

These log tables can have lots of data, so I was wandering if it is a nice idea to move all of them to a different catalog such as `db_log` (or if I must keep the log tables in the catalogs they are now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs are mostly used for auditing purposes and to keep history of what-happened and who-dun-it. If you have a database called db_operations and table such as tb_customer, I recommend that your log-table tb_log_customer be in the same database (db_operations).

Keeping them in the same database will allow you to take backups of both customer and customer-log table as a single unit of work. If your log was in a different database such as db_logs, you would have to back up db_operations and db_logs at the same time and still not get a pristine restore. Same issue applies to log shipping and mirroring techniques.

To manage the log tables, I'd recommend creating filegroup(s). Log tables can go on these filegroup(s) and the path for the filegroup can be a different volume/controller. To manage the size of the log files, I propose deleting history after a certain period of time. I'd recommend taking a look at [partitioning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) as well.